# Required columns are not present in the data frame but column header gets created in the csv and all rows gets populated with null

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working on getting data from an API using python. The API returns data in form of json which is being normalised and written to a data frame which is then written to a csv file.
The API can return any number of columns which differs between each records. I need only a fixed number of columns which i am defining in the code.
In the scenario where the required column is not being returned my code fails. 
I need a solution where even though required columns are not present in the data frame column header gets created in the csv and all rows gets populated with null.

required csv structure :
name address phone
abc bcd 1214
bcd null null

Comment: Current code :
column_needed=['name',address,'phone']
response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
result=json.loads(response.content)
DF_New=pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(result['sentences']))
DF.to_csv(f,index=False,sep='\t',columms=column_needed)

Comment: Could you provide an example of json data with all the possible fields presented?

Comment: {
"sentences" : {
    "name" : "abc"
    "address" : "bcd"
    "married" " "true"
    "phone" : 6576
    }
}

Comment: Is the "sentences" field always dict or it might be list of dicts? In other words is it a correct json: { "sentences" : [{ "name" : "abc" "address" : "bcd" "married" " "true" "phone" : 6576 }, { "name" : "def" "address" : "ghi" "married" " "true" "phone" : 7687 }] }?

Comment: json looks correct

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if understood you correctly but I hope the following code solves your problem:

```
import json

import pandas as pd

# Declare json with missing values:
# - First element doesn't contain "phone" field
# - Second element doesn't contain "married" field
api_data = """
{ "sentences" : 
[
{ "name": "abc", "address": "bcd", "married": true}, 
{ "name": "def", "address": "ghi", "phone" : 7687 }
] 
}
"""

json_data = json.loads(api_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=json_data["sentences"], 
    # Explicitly declare which columns should be presented in DataFrame
    # If value for given column is absent it will be populated with NaN
    columns=["name", "address", "married", "phone"]
)

# Save result to csv:
df.to_csv("tmp.csv", index=False)
```

The content of resulting csv:

```
name,address,married,phone
abc,bcd,True,
def,ghi,,7687.0
```

**P.S.:**
It should work even if columns are absent in all the records. Here is another example:

```
# Both elements do not contain "married" and "phone" fields
api_data = """
{ "sentences" : 
[
{ "name": "abc", "address": "bcd"}, 
{ "name": "def", "address": "ghi"}
] 
}
"""

json_data = json.loads(api_data)
json_data["sentences"][0]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=json_data["sentences"], 
    # Explicitly declare which columns should be presented in DataFrame
    # If value for given column is absent it will be populated with NaN
    columns=["name", "address", "married", "phone"]
)

# Print first rows of DataFrame:
df.head()
# Expected output:
#  name address  married  phone
# 0  abc     bcd      NaN    NaN
# 1  def     ghi      NaN    NaN

df.to_csv("tmp.csv", index=False)
```

In this case the resulting csv file will contain the following text:

```
name,address,married,phone
abc,bcd,,
def,ghi,,
```

The last two commas in the 2nd and 3d lines mean "an empty/missing value" and if you create DataFrame from resulting csv by `pd.read_csv` then "married" and "phone" columns will be populated with NaN values.

Comment: This code will work if we get all columns everytime but thats not the case. We might get only 3 or 2 columns at times, in that scenario this code will fail.
I need a solution where even if required columns are not returned, column header gets created in the csv

Comment: Hm, It seems strange because it either does work in my configuration (I have pandas 0.24.2 and Python 3.6.9) either I don't fully understand your needs. Anyway I have updated my answer, hope it will help.

Comment: This solution is not working for me because my columns name has full stop in them. Like 'city.address' or 'firstname.secondname'
Because of the full stop even though the column value is being returned from the API, the CSV doesn't have it. Can you help with names with full stop?